# Передача соединения с бд в функцию

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, sqlite

Что будет, если передать соединение с базой данных в функцию, которая будет работать в другом потоке, а в основном потоке закрыть соединение? И закроется ли соединение, если использовать with-statement?

Функция работающая в потоке, использующая соединение с базой данных для чтения и записи

```
def post(db, states, user_list)
```

Работа с базой данных:

```
class SQLighter:
    def __init__(self, database=config.database_name):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def close(self):
        """ Закрываем текущее соединение с БД """
        self.connection.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, Type, Value, Trace):
        self.close()
```

Открываю соединение в основном процессе:

```
with SQLighter() as db:
    pub_thread = Thread(target=post, args=(db, states_for_thread, user_ids))
    pub_thread.start()
    # do other work
```

Как в таком случае будет отрабатывать функция post?
Использую базу данных SQLite и Python3

Comment: Закроется и получите ошибку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да, получил ошибку. Спасибо за ответ. Созрел следущий вопрос. Как лучше поступить - открыть одно соединение на все время выполнения функции post или внутри нее дергать другие функции, которые открывают соединение, делают работу и закрывают соединение с базой?

Comment: Невозможно дать однозначный ответ, зависит от множества факторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае будет ошибка при запуске — с SQLite невозможно взаимодействовать из разных потоков.

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 14612 and this is thread id 19144